Are there instances of hostility between Brahma and Indra in the scriptures?
Since Brahma is the deity who often grants boons to Asuras, Rakshasas et al who torment the Devas - has Indra shown hostility towards Brahma in any scripture?

Bc the gods are free from reality they can be however without our problems
